# kivy: Precise focus placement cursor between characters in a widget

Tags: python, kivy

How can I change the cursor focus between characters ?
My widget add `/` to help writing the date but the cursor focus stay behind the `/` character that I added. I would like to advance this one after the character.

MVP:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

def on_text(instance, value):
    if len(value) == 2:
        if value[:2].isdigit():
            instance.text += "/"
    if len(value) == 5:
        if value[3:5].isdigit():
            instance.text += "/"
    print('The widget', instance, 'have:', value)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        text_input = TextInput()
        text_input.bind(text=on_text)
        return text_input

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach is to just over-ride the `insert_text()` method of the `TextInput`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        value = self.text + substring
        if len(value) == 2:
            if value[:2].isdigit():
                substring += "/"
        if len(value) == 5:
            if value[3:5].isdigit():
                substring += "/"
        return super(MyTextInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        text_input = MyTextInput()
        # text_input.bind(text=on_text)
        return text_input

MyApp().run()
```

Note that using an `on_text()` method to modify the `text` results in additional calls to `on_text()` and can easily result in an infinite loop.